# Locating canvas objects with Selenium

Tags: selenium, canvas

I'm using Selenium to develop automated tests for a web application. I have to simulate clicks on certain objects that reside inside a canvas element. In particular, I'm using [vis.js](http://visjs.org/) to visualize nodes/edges and I need to test the effect of clicking on particular nodes/edges that are visible on the canvas.

The problem is that the positions of the nodes/edges aren't determined in advance. Therefore, I'm not sure how I'm supposed to locate them. If I were able to find the coordinates of a canvas object's position, it would've been possible for me to simulate clicking on the object using Selenium's [moveByOffset](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html#moveByOffset-int-int-):

```
x, y = find_node_coordinates_on_canvas(node_id) # how to do this?
canvas = self.driver.find_element_by_id("vis_canvas")
action = ActionChains(self.driver).move_by_offset(x, y).click(canvas).release()
```

The problem is that I don't know how to implement `find_node_coordinates_on_canvas`. That is, given the identifier of an object on the canvas, how do I find the coordinates of its position?